# Google Drive API - Permission error with script to update permissions for shared drives members

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I am trying to create a Google Apps Script that updates the permissions of members of shared drives, from a Google Sheet, with the shared drive ID in column A, the permission ID in column G (one per row), the permission role in column E (one per row), the additionalRoles (if any, for commenters) in column F (one per row), and the email address of the user in column D.

I have also included (in the script) the additional args "supportsAllDrives: true" and "useDomainAdminAccess: true".

The script has the OAuth2 and the services "Drive" and AdminDirectory".

[image: Library and services]

---

I'm using a super admin account (I've also tried using a service account with domain-wide delegation and user impersonation), but I always get the same error:

[image: Error message: "An error occurred: API call to drive.permissions.patch failed with error: The authenticated user does not have the required access to update the permission."]

The error messages says: "An error occurred: API call to drive.permissions.patch failed with error: The authenticated user does not have the required access to update the permission."

Despite the error, some permissions are updated. Others aren't, no matter if I try with 1 or with 30 shared drives, or with 1 or 30 members, or with only one type of permissions or with all of them.

---

But if I use the "Try it" API tool available at https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/permissions/patch (in the right-panel), everything works.

The  script that I am using is as follows:

```
function updateSharedDrivePermissions() {
  try {
    var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("GetUsers");
    var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
    var data = sheet.getRange(2, 1, lastRow - 1, 7).getValues();
  
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      var sharedDriveId = data[i][0];
      var permissionId = data[i][6];
      var key = data[i][4];
//      var additionalRoles = data[i][5]; // to use later, for commenters
      var email = data[i][3];


 var resource = {
            role: key,
            type: "user",
            value: email,
          }
 // optional arguments to work on Shared drive
          var optionalArgs = {
          sendNotificationEmails: false,
            useDomainAdminAccess: true,
            supportsAllDrives: true
          }

          // set Shared drive permissions
          Drive.Permissions.patch(resource, sharedDriveId, permissionId, optionalArgs);


    // Send a message to the user
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert("Shared drive permissions updated successfully!");
  } catch (error) {
    // Handle the error
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert("An error occurred: " + error.message);
    // log error message for debugging purposes
    console.log(error.message);
  }
}
```

I've tried everything I can think of.

Additionally, some shared drive let me downgrade the permissions to "reader" while others don't. I believe this must be related to the pre-existence or not of the "commnenter" additionalRoles.

But - also for this - if I use the "Try it" API tool available at https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/permissions/patch (in the right-panel), everything works.

---

Note: the admin/user executing the script is a Manager in all the tested shared drives.

---

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Have you tried adding the service account or any of the Admin users as a "Content Manager" in at least one o the Shared drives?

Comment: The admin/user executing the script is a Manager in all the tested shared drives.